# Average from multiple arrays in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate the average from multiple (json) arrays in Postgres.

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE marks (student varchar(48), year int , testresult json);

INSERT INTO marks 
VALUES ('John',2017,'[7.3,8.1,9.2]'),
      ('Mary', 2017, '[6.1,7.4,5.6]'), 
     ('Tim',2017,'[6.3,5.6,8.3]');
```

There are 3 students in 2017 that all have taken 3 tests. I want to calculate the average of the tests for all students in 2017 (with n precision).

Have tried it myself, and only achieved the following until now:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/58f38/44

So I want to get the following result:

```
student|  year | averages   
-------+-------+-----------
All    |  2017 | [6.567, 7.033, 7.700]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `unnest`, do calculation and aggregate back to JSON format:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 'All' AS student, year, AVG(unnest::decimal(10,2)) AS av
   FROM marks,
   unnest(ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements_text(testresult))) with ordinality
   GROUP BY year, ordinality
)
SELECT student, year, array_to_json(array_agg(av::decimal(10,3))) AS averages
FROM cte
GROUP BY student, year;
```

Output:

```
+---------+------+---------------------+
| student | year |      averages       |
+---------+------+---------------------+
| All     | 2017 | [6.567,7.033,7.700] |
+---------+------+---------------------+
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=21a9b7d9010b14822a756f29c6ea3e2a)**

Comment: Great! Thanks for your fast and helpful answer. So as I understand correctly, the array is split and the ordinality keeps the original order? And then the averages are concatenated to a new array again?

Comment: @web_student Yes, exactly.

Comment: I have tried this query and it works. Expect when I try I it with a large dataset (30K+ records) and when the averages json column contains a large json array (60k+ elements) I can't execute the query, getting the following error: invalid memory alloc request size. Is this only due to the large size of the dataset?

Comment: @web_student Well, number of rows matters.

Comment: i believe you should also have an "order by ordinality"

Comment: @pstanton Could you elaborate or provide a sample code based on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=21a9b7d9010b14822a756f29c6ea3e2a ?

Comment: i found that the ordering of "ordinality" is not implicit so, after "GROUP BY" I needed "ORDER BY" as well. In your case, `... ORDER BY year, ordinality`

Comment: @pstanton I think I still miss your point. I agree that in order to have specific order there should be order by but in aggregate function. Unless you mean a `ORDER BY` inside cte like [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3228b6b82799250632687df49a3cba31)

Comment: i do mean inside `cte`. your case may work fine due to the "natural" order but mine did not. solved by adding order as described.